# Replacing characters in a string using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, character

I have researched about character replacement using dictionaries but I still cannot get my code to work properly. My code goes like this:

```
def encode(code,msg):  
    for k in code:  
        msg = msg.replace(k,code[k])  
    return msg
```

Now, when I run the code:

```
code = {'e':'x','x':'e'}
msg = "Jimi Hendrix"
encode(code,msg)
```

It gives me "Jimi Hxndrix" instead of "Jimi Hxndrie".  How do I get the letter 'x' to be replaced by 'e' also?

Comment: You are replacing only the *first* occurrence of `x` for `e`, then the *first* occurrence of `e` for `x`. Thus, `Jimi Hendrix` becomes `Jimi Hendrie`, then `Jimi Hxndrie`. `.replace()` is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters No. If one executes ``msg = msg.replace(k,code[k])`` followed by ``print k,' ',msg`` on "Jimi Hendrix fixed the axes" , it prints firstly **Jimi Hendrie fieed the aees** then **Jimi Hxndrix fixxd thx axxs** . That's because **code** is a dictionary that is not iterated in the order 'e' then 'x' but in the order 'x' first and 'e' after. And all the occurences of a character in a string are replaced, not only the first one.

Answer (score 9):

You can look at `str.translate` or do:

```
''.join(code.get(ch, ch) for ch in msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `maketrans` and `translate`:

```
from string import maketrans
msg.translate(maketrans(''.join(code.keys()), ''.join(code.values())))
```

Comment: I think that the correct way should be 

    msg.translate(maketrans(''.join(code.values()), ''.join(code.keys())))
instead of 

    msg.translate(maketrans(''.join(code.keys()), ''.join(code.values())))

Although, in this case the result would be the same.

Comment: @Nikpa usually you'd write the dictionary as `{from: to}`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you iterate on **code** instead on **msg**

Iterating on **msg** is what is done in Jon Clements' program, which can be written more explicitly as

```
print ''.join(code[ch] if ch in code else ch for ch in msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're swapping x and e; it is overwriting your previous edits.

You should copy from an old string to a new one (or rather, an array of chars, since as Kalle pointed out strings are "immutable"/not editable), so that you don't overwrite characters you've already replaced:

```
def encode(code, message):
    encoded = [c for c in message]
    for i, c in enumerate(message):
        try:
            encoded[i] = code[c]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return ''.join(encoded)
```

the other answers are library functions which do something like this, but they don't explain where you went wrong.

Comment: Does not work, since strings are [*immutable*](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-are-python-strings-immutable), i.e. you may not change an existing string using operations like `encoded[i] = code[c]`

Comment: thanks, missed that. now using an array of chars instead. (I'm sure that would work in Ruby - I never figured out the differences in string handling in both languages. I use python a lot, just not for string operations!)

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2
     use your own code it is ok.

     def encode(code,msg):  
                for k in code:  
                       msg = msg.replace(k,code[k],1)  
                return msg

       ##  str.replace(old,new,[,count])
      so when you loop in your code = {'e':'x','x':'e'}
      first it gets the key "x" then the key "e" because dict is not ordered
      so,  "Hendrix" turns into "Hendrie" then "Hendrie" turns into Hxndrix and
     you are not having your result. but if you add 1 in your code
      msg.replace(k,code[k],1) then it only will replace one letter per loop and you                                    
      have your result Try.
```