# Why replace method is adding more elements rather than replacing existing ones?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code that changes a letter to another according to a dictionary. If it finds the letter "o" in a string, it changes to "e", for example. The way I came up with technically worked but still adds more elements for some reason and I couldn't figure it out unfortunately. (Python beginner)
Here is the code:

```
dict1 = {"o":"e", "p":"l"}
text = "op"
text2 = ""
for key,value in dict1.items():
    y = text.replace(key,value)
    text2 +=y
print(text2)
```

Comment: `print(y)` on each iteration and see what you have.

Comment: See  [Best way to replace multiple characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: CaptainTrojan's answer addresses your direct problem. For a more general solution, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626728/replacing-characters-in-a-string-using-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You're performing key-wise updates and appending them to an empty string. Just use

```
dict1 = {"o":"e", "p":"l"}
text = "op"
for key,value in dict1.items():
    text = text.replace(key,value)
print(text)
```

Your values of `y` and `text2`:

1. `y='ep'` -> `text2 = '' + 'ep' = 'ep'`
2. `y='ol'` -> `text2 = 'ep' + 'ol' = 'epol'`

Comment: This will not work in a more general case, though, where some replacements might be replaced again later.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille It is the smallest update to OP's code. If they wanted to fix their algorithm logic, I would iterate over text characters and not the update characters for the whole text at once, but hey.